# Hadoop/Hbase performance improvement of bulk loading

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am loading 10 million records into Hbase table through importsv tool from hadoop multinode cluster. Right now it is taking 5 minutes for this task. But i was wondering how i could improve the performance of this. The importtsv tool does not seem like using reducers at all. I was wondering if i could anyway force this to use reducers, it could improve performance or any other way which you think would improve the performance would be appreciated.
 Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Importtsv with HfileOutPutFormat , completeBulkLoadTool.

Answer (score 1):

when it comes to performance, there is no easy answer. If the 5 minutes equals to the speed of the network, or the speed of the hard disk, you have to move the source data to somewhere else or change the hardware.

I don't know importsv. I would suggest you to try multi-way load. Take a look at Sqoop.

Comment: Thanx for the reply, will look at sqoop, but thats for relational databases, i am using non-relational database.

Answer (score 0):

You can get best HBase bulk load performance with use of `HFileOutputFormat` and `CompleteBulkLoad`

Check [here](http://databuff.blogspot.com/2013/11/bulk-load-data-in-hbase-table.html#.V3-BVut9744).